# move clip area to center of canvas, Fabric js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I was created a clipped area in canvas by using fabricjs, 
HERE is the clipped area i have created,

```js
var canvasDefaultWidth  = 350;
var canvasDefaultHeight = 180;

var targetCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

canvas = new fabric.Canvas(targetCanvas);

canvas.setWidth(canvasDefaultWidth);
canvas.setHeight(canvasDefaultHeight);

canvas.backgroundColor = '#fff';
canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {                     
  ctx.beginPath();
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: '#fff',
    opacity: 1,
    left: 35,
    top: 15,
    width: 280,
    height: 150,
  });
  rect.render(ctx);
}
canvas.controlsAboveOverlay = true;

var text = new fabric.IText('Lorem Ipsum Dolla');
canvas.add(text);

canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
html{background:#cfcfcf}
canvas{ border: 1px solid #000; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.2/fabric.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

I used left and top attribute to move clipped area go center and middle of canvas manually, is that posibble to make clipped area go center and middle of canvas by automatic although i increase canvas size or decrease clipped area size ??